# getting the IntPtr to an IWin32Window to replace AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()

Tags: c#, winforms, intptr

Hi in c# WinForms in order to replace the deprecated `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` I have to consider the following

```
...
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

private static IWin32Window _owner;
...
```

## #

```
uint processID = 0;
IntPtr ptr =  _owner.Handle.ToPointer();
GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out processID);
int replacementCurrentThreadId = processID;
```

Except it doesn't work - the errors are

`The best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments`

or

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'void*' to 'System.IntPtr'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

I believe I have the right approach (to get the currentThreadId) but it will not *let* me assign values - presumably because they are pointers (?)  Any help would be apprciated

Comment: Don't use Handle.ToPointer(), just Handle.  Use this instead: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetCurrentThreadId.html